# How to use X,Y, and Z instead of Pitch, Roll and Yaw

Tags: unreal-4, coordinates

I'm learning Unreal engine, and I'm rather disappointed because it uses pitch roll and yaw instead of the standard x, y, and z that I'm used to.  Is there any way to convert this easily, or is there a preference, or do  I have to get used to using y,z,x, instead of x,y,z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're trying to do, both rotational and vector coordinates are normally available. The following C++/Blueprint methods are available to move between the two different types of coordinate systems. Hope it helps!

## [FRotator](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FRotator/index.html)

Represents rotational coordinates (yaw, pitch, roll).

**C++:**
[FRotator::Vector()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FRotator/Vector/index.html)

**Blueprints:**
[Break Rot Into Axes](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Rotator/BreakRotIntoAxes/index.html)

## [FVector](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FRotator/Vector/index.html)

Represents vector coordinates (x, y, z).

**C++:**
[FVector::Rotation()](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Math/FVector/Rotation/index.html)

**Blueprints:**
[Rotator from Axis and Angle](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Vector/RotatorfromAxisandAngle/index.html)

## Other Conversions

[Here's a list of other conversions.](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Conversions/index.html) This may not be an exhaustive list as their code changes from version to version often. So, navigating the engine's source code on your computer will be the the final source of truth.